# trying to create configmap which takes the config from environments folder. but unable to find correct syntax

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I am creating configmap YAML file using helm, we are injecting JSON data from respective environments folders, but could not get exact helm syntax.

we have a folder structure like files/Dev, files/Tst, Files/ACC, files/PRD

I have environment variable in **values_dev.yaml**

environment: Dev

my configmap.yaml

```yaml
data: {{- .Files.Get "files/%s/*".Values.environment" | fromJson | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
```

but it did not work.. any help is much-appreciated .thanks in advance

Comment: how many files do you have in `files/Dev` and what's their format

Comment: it is only one json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to [inject Configmap data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap) into a volume

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap
data: 
{{- range $path, $_ :=  .Files.Glob  (printf "files/%s/*" .Values.environment ) }}
  {{ base $path }}: |-
{{ $.Files.Get $path | indent 4 }} 
{{ end }}
```

If you want to [configure all key-value pairs in a ConfigMap as container environment variables](http://Configure%20all%20key-value%20pairs%20in%20a%20ConfigMap%20as%20container%20environment%20variables)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap
data: 
{{ $files := (.Files.Glob (printf "files/%s/*" .Values.environment ) ) }}
{{- range $k,$v := $files }}
  {{ $file := fromJson ($.Files.Get $k)  }}
  {{- range $key,$val := $file }}
    {{- $key | squote }}: {{ $val | squote }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

File structure

```
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── files
│   └── dev
│       └── file1.json
├── templates
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── configmap.yaml
│   └── pod.yaml
└── values.yaml
```